how to check logs for a glue trigger job?
I have aws glue resources set up , which if i run manually from the browser works. to automate this i added  aws_glue_trigger resource with a condition that , if the crawler succeeds then i fire off the glue job.
i'm testing this , but nothing happens after the crawler succeeds. i don't see  where i can check if the trigger was invoked , nor i can see if trigger was invoked but the glue job was triggered or not?
resource "aws_glue_crawler" "crawler"{
    name ="some_crawler"
    role = aws_iam_role.role.arn
    ....
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "role"{
   name="some_role"
   assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
       Statement = [{
           Action="sts:AssumeRole"
           Effect="Allow"
           Principal = { Service = "glue.amazonaws.com"}
       ]
   })
}
resource "aws_glue_trigger" "trigger" {
  name = "trigger"
  type = "CONDITIONAL"

  actions {
    job_name = aws_glue_job.job.name
  }

  predicate {
    conditions {
      crawler_name = aws_glue_crawler.crawler.name
      crawl_state  = "SUCCEEDED"
    }
  }
}
resource "aws_glue_job" "job"{
}


If such an option exists, you probably need to configure CloudWatch logs.
